# Connection to Google Spreadsheets not opening in Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny-server

I have been trying to use Shiny to read and analyze new format Google spreadsheets using the functions [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/06/reading-data-from-the-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets.html).

This works fine locally but not when I deploy to shinyapps.io.

One issue was the known issue of false positives on the test for absolute paths but that is solved by forcing deployment in the console.  However once uploaded  I'm getting the javascript dump alert with this error

```
label, label<-Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

I've looked around and I can see that people get the javascript error dump for a lot of reasons, and the closest I  saw was where someone needed to use RCurl, but that didn't help me. I also know that I have https in the url so that is not the issue. The spreadsheet I am reading is definitely published to the web; anything obvious like that would have made it not work locally.

Update: I'll copy the code for the functions here.

```
library(XML)

cleanGoogleTable <- function(dat, table=1, skip=0,

ncols=NA, nrows=-1, header=TRUE, dropFirstCol=NA){  

if(!is.data.frame(dat)) {

    dat <- dat[[table]]   }   if(is.na(dropFirstCol)) {
    firstCol <- na.omit(dat[[1]])
    if(all(firstCol == ".") || all(firstCol== as.character(seq_along(firstCol)))) {

      dat <- dat[, -1]
    }   } else if(dropFirstCol) {
    dat <- dat[, -1]   }   if(skip > 0){
    dat <- dat[-seq_len(skip), ]   }   if(nrow(dat) == 1) return(dat)   if(nrow(dat) >= 2){
    if(all(is.na(dat[2, ]))) dat <- dat[-2, ]   }   if(header && nrow(dat) > 1){
    header <- as.character(dat[1, ])
    names(dat) <- header
    dat <- dat[-1, ]   }   # Keep only desired columns   if(!is.na(ncols)){

    ncols <- min(ncols, ncol(dat))
    dat <- dat[, seq_len(ncols)]   }   # Keep only desired rows   if(nrows > 0){
    nrows <- min(nrows, nrow(dat))
    dat <- dat[seq_len(nrows), ]   }   # Rename rows   rownames(dat) <- seq_len(nrow(dat))   dat }
```

and

```
readGoogleSheet <- function(url, na.string="", header=TRUE){
  stopifnot(require(XML))
  # Suppress warnings because Google docs seems to have incomplete final line
  suppressWarnings({
    doc <- paste(readLines(url), collapse=" ")
  })
  if(nchar(doc) == 0) stop("No content found")
  htmlTable <- gsub("^.*?(<table.*</table).*$", "\\1>", doc)
  ret <- readHTMLTable(htmlTable, header=header, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.data.frame=TRUE)
  lapply(ret, function(x){ x[ x == na.string] <- NA; x})
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `readGoogleSheet()` function which uses `readLines()` which calls `url()` which only supports `https`  on Windows, which is what I'm on locally.  Google, of course, is end to end `https`.

To get it to run I made this change

```
 +doc <- content(GET(url), as="text")
 -doc <- paste(readLines(url), collapse=" ")
```

and that seemed to work.  I got the general idea for this from @hrbmstr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700909/line-by-line-reading-of-https-connection-in-r)

Comment: I was having this exact issue - made the change as directed to the readGoogleSheet function and now it works when deployed to ShinyApps.

Comment: I have successfully used your function to read a Google spreadsheet, with no errors.  However, only the first 100 rows of the spreadsheet are being read (it has a few hundred rows).  Did you run into similar limitations?  Any suggestions for how I can get around this issue?  I found another post referring to this 100 row limit in a web query, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772346/using-an-excel-web-query-to-transfer-data-from-a-google-sheet-limits-to-100-rows.