# Line by line reading from HTTPS connection in R

Tags: r, http, rcurl, httr

When a connection is created with `open="r"` it allows for line-by-line reading, which is useful  for batch processing large data streams. For example [this script](https://gist.github.com/jeroenooms/d33a24958d99bb969ac0) parses a sizable gzipped JSON HTTP stream by reading 100 lines at a time. However unfortunately R does not support SSL:

```
> readLines(url("https://api.github.com/repos/jeroenooms/opencpu"))
Error in readLines(url("https://api.github.com/repos/jeroenooms/opencpu")) : 
  cannot open the connection: unsupported URL scheme
```

The `RCurl` and `httr` packages do support HTTPS, but I don't think they are capable of creating a connection object similar to `url()`. Is there some other way to do line-by-line reading of an HTTPS connection similar to the example in the script above?

Comment: +1: Note that `?url` says `"https://"` *is* supported on Windows (in certain circumstances) and directs users to the `method` argument set to `"wget"` and/or `"lynx"` of `download.file` (but these don't solve Jeron's problem).

Comment: `readLines(textConnection(content(GET("https://api.github.com/repos/jeroenooms/opencpu"), as="text")))` might do the trick, but `GET` is going to grab the whole file first. `httr` now supports downloading content to disk, which may not be optimal, but is an alternative if the object won't fit into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to manually call the `curl` executable via `pipe`. The following seems to work.

```
library(jsonlite)
stream_https <- gzcon(pipe("curl https://jeroenooms.github.io/files/hourly_14.json.gz", open="r"))
batches <- list(); i <- 1
while(length(records <- readLines(gzstream, n = 100))){
  message("Batch ", i, ": found ", length(records), " lines of json...")
  json <- paste0("[", paste0(records, collapse=","), "]")
  batches[[i]] <- fromJSON(json, validate=TRUE)
  i <- i+1
}
weather <- rbind.pages(batches)
rm(batches); close(gzstream)
```

However this is suboptimal because the `curl` executable might not be available for various reasons. Would be much nicer to invoke this pipe directly via RCurl/libcurl.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, RCurl can "do line-by-line reading".  In fact, it always does it, but the higher level functions hide this for you for convenience.  You use the writefunction (and headerfunction for the header) to specify a function that is called each time libcurl has received enough bytes from the body of the result. That function can do anything it wants. There are several examples of this in the RCurl package itself.  But here is a simple one

```
curlPerform(url = "http://www.omegahat.org/index.html", 
            writefunction = function(txt, ...) { 
                                 cat("*", txt, "\n")
                                 TRUE
                            })
```

Comment: For future reference, a worked out example: https://gist.github.com/jeroenooms/d1e48644fa6044722b09