# How can a shiny app handle read.csv of an https located csv file the way a local instance can?

Tags: r, https, google-sheets, shiny, read.csv

I have a shinyapps.io application running fine, referencing a number of google sheets (by using publish->csv). This means that I can read.csv(url) those https://... urls both locally and in my shiny app. That's excellent.

However, one of my data partners offered up a csv file at their own https location, and that time the application failed with

> "ERROR: cannot open the connection to
>   'https://www.ncdetect.com/PublicDownload/OverdoseReport.csv'"

I've seem a handful of seemingly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816986/using-a-downloaded-external-file-in-shiny-app/45763815#45763815) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892466/read-csv-from-zip-into-shiny-app-without-relying-on-local-directories) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965979/data-object-not-found-when-deploying-shiny-app), though none ended up being helpful.

The (public data) file I can read.csv() with in a shiny app is here, even though it's downloadable and my local instance can handle it just fine: https://www.ncdetect.com/PublicDownload/OverdoseReport.csv .

Comment: Can you expand upon how you use publish->csv and then read.csv(url)? Sorry I don't think I can help you with this question but I am very curious about what you mentioned here.

Comment: Google sheets go to File, then Publish to Web. That can host a csv version of your google sheet that R can read in using read.csv("url-goes-here"). Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!